# Converting data frame (factors) with data.matrix, weird results

Tags: r

I don't understand the result of data.matrix on my data frame. The goal is to barplot the results. Datas :

```
> tab.c.graph
    BacD BacE BacF
J01    2    6   10
J02    2    2    0
J03    9    4    6
J04    1    7    3
J05   11   10    2
J06    9    7    7
J07    8    3    0
J08    6    2    1
J09    4    3    2
J10    4    4    1
> str(tab.c.graph)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ BacD: Factor w/ 8 levels "1","11","2"," 2",..: 4 3 8 1 2 8 7 6 5 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "J01" "J02" "J03" "J04" ...
 $ BacE: Factor w/ 6 levels "10","2","3","4",..: 5 2 4 6 1 6 3 2 3 4
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "J01" "J02" "J03" "J04" ...
 $ BacF: Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","10","2",..: 3 1 7 6 5 8 1 2 4 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "J01" "J02" "J03" "J04" ...

> data.matrix(tab.c.graph)
    BacD BacE BacF
J01    4    5    3
J02    3    2    1
J03    8    4    7
J04    1    6    6
J05    2    1    5
J06    8    6    8
J07    7    3    1
J08    6    2    2
J09    5    3    4
J10    5    4    2

> str(data.matrix(tab.c.graph))
 int [1:10, 1:3] 4 3 8 1 2 8 7 6 5 5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "J01" "J02" "J03" "J04" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "BacD" "BacE" "BacF"
```

Why is data.matrix so different from my data.frame ? As mention above, I just need to plot these datas.

Thanx for helping !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what happened, look at the following example:

```
> (f <- gl(2, 1, 10, labels=3:4))
 [1] 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4
Levels: 3 4
> as.numeric(f)
 [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
> as.numeric(as.character(f))
 [1] 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4
```

To convert a *factor* (which is what you have in your `data.frame`) into a `numeric` vector while preserving its *labels* (otherwise you'll just get its *levels*), you need something like `as.numeric(as.character())`.

So, either ensure that you read your input data correctly (if numbers are quoted, with `options("stringsAsFactors")` set to TRUE, then it's likely they will be converted to a factor), or convert your data.frame afterwards. This can be done columnwise, e.g.

```
dfrm <- data.frame(x=factor(c(3,2,1,8,4)), y=factor(c(5,6,1,2,3)))
m <- sapply(dfrm, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
plot(m)
```

---

I misread your question and I thought you were using `as.matrix`, not `data.matrix`. That doesn't change anything, since both functions will convert factors into their internal representation, as stated in the on-line help:

> Factors and ordered factors are replaced by their internal codes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I already tried to convert my factors with : > as.numeric(as.character(tab.c.graph)) but I get NAs introduced by coercion error and > levels(tab.c.graph) gives me NULL, so all factors in my table are numbers...

Comment: You cannot get levels on an entire data.frame. You need to use levels(tab.c.graph$BacD) if you wnat to look at the levels before conversion for that particular factor.

Comment: Yes, got the conversion to work. Your explanations helped me a lot. Thanx !